# Cordova/Phonegap OpenEars speech recognition

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, plugins, openears

I am trying including the OpenEars plugin into phonegap/cordova using this plugin https://github.com/karljacuncha/OpenEarsPlugin

I followed the Readme but i ended up with an error of missing files, all these files are not found :(

[image]

Any help/suggestion on how to integrate the library?

thank you any advice appreciated!

Comment: The problem is most probably in that the new OpenEars version was released 5th of December, where that file was removed. I'm looking for older version / way to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned on a comment, new, non-backwards compatible version (2.0) of [OpenEars](http://www.politepix.com/openears) was [released](http://www.politepix.com/2014/12/05/openears-2-0-and-version-2-0-of-all-plugins-out-now/) on 5th of December in 2014. This of course prevents it from working with old code such as the plugin in this case.

Basically there would be two options to get it working:

1. Use older version of OpenEars (last one was 1.7.1) but that doesn't seem to be possible as I wasn't able to download it from anywhere after extensive search.
2. Fix the code to work on newest OpenEars. It shouldn't be that hard and the code of plugin is only ~400 lines of code. Most of the changes are quite straightforward as described in the [upgrade guide](http://www.politepix.com/upgradeguide). Feel free to fork the project in GitHub or try to contact the original author of that plugin to make the fixes necessary.

Comment: thank you man, seriously! just i am not so good outside of javascript so i think i can't help much :(

Comment: any news? :) I am still looking for some good plugin for STT on phonegap :(

Comment: Looked into it and didn't find anything yet. You should though keep an eye on [this](https://github.com/karljacuncha/OpenEarsPlugin/issues/2) as the GitHub user _batilc1_ says he is trying to port it.

Comment: Anyone got any further on this?